How do i get my Python .env credentials file into Ubuntu EC2?
I have a .env file which my app.py file references, containing my AWS credentials. How do i get this into my AWS Ubuntu EC2 machine?
I can't even upload it to GitHub.
If there's any security issues with this, whats the simplest workaround strategy you use? Worst case i could hardcode it, but i don't think that's ideal.

The way to supply AWS credentials to applications running on EC2 is via an IAM role.

I have an IAM role, thats how i have the access keys. These keys are referenced in the .env file by the Python app running in the EC2. But HOW to get the .env into the Ubuntu machine?

Change the Python application to use the aws sdk/cli to read the access key.
I recommend that you do not store credentials in the .env file. Store the credentials in AWS Parameter Store or AWS Secrets Manager and then attach an IAM Role in EC2 that allows your application to read the credentials from Parameter Store or Secrets Manager

How many sets of AWS credentials are you talking about here? If it's one set then use an IAM role on EC2 and you can use them via an AWS SDK on your EC2 instance (the SDK will auto-fetch them) or you can fetch them from the instance metadata service (IMDS) on the EC2 instance.

The best strategy is using secrets manager and make api calls to retrieve the secret value, of course your ec2 instance role must have iam permissions to get the secret
